# Local-scoped coordinate names in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I think I just discovered (!) that coordinates names are global in `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[black]
    \draw(0,0) coordinate(alfa) -- (3,0) coordinate(beta);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
    \draw (alfa) -- (beta);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
    \begin{scope}
        \draw(1,0) coordinate(alfa) -- (2,0) coordinate(beta);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[green]
    \draw (alfa) -- (beta);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: four silly lines]

...and I really expected

1. an error in the second `tikzpicture` (I am not using `remember picture`!), and
2. a `(0,0)--(3,0)` green line...

So,

1. am I correct that coordinate names are global to all `tikzpicture`s?
2. As a bonus question, is it possible to create local coordinate names?

Comment: +1 I didn't know that either. On page `983` we find this, and I quote: `\pgfgetlastxy{macro for x}{macro for y} Since (x,y) coordinates are usually assigned globally, it is safe to use this command after path operations`

Comment: I am intested in the bonus question: Is it possible to create local coordinate names? Anyone can answer?

Comment: @BlackMild yes, using `name prefix` - it's in the accepted answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I've observed that before. And I think your interpretation is correct, and you can make coordinates "local" by using `name prefix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[black]
    \draw(0,0) coordinate(alfa) -- (3,0) coordinate(beta);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blue]
    \draw (alfa) -- (beta);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[red,name prefix=Rmano]
    \begin{scope}
        \draw(1,0) coordinate(alfa) -- (2,0) coordinate(beta);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[green]
    \draw (alfa) -- (beta);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, `name prefix` is a nice trick. Thanks!